# ¿Cómo pasar texto a número con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código el cual, la idea es que convierta un precio, por ejemplo así (₡5,000.00) a número para poder sumarlo en un carrito de compras.

```
const shoppingCartItemPrice = Number(
  shoppingCartItemPriceElement.textContent.replace('₡', '')
);
console.log(shoppingCartItemPrice);
```

Pero por consola me imprime lo siguiente: `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo así (es un ejemplo forzado, recuerda que el tuyo es un `textContent`):

```js
let shoppingCartItemPriceElement = "₡5,000.00"
let sinMoneda = shoppingCartItemPriceElement.replace('₡', '').replace(',','').replace('.',',')
const shoppingCartItemPrice = parseFloat(sinMoneda);
console.log(shoppingCartItemPrice);
```

De este modo le quitas el símbolo de moneda `₡`, y lo pones en formato correcto para javascript quitándo la **coma** de los miles, y poniéndole la **coma** a los decimales sustituyendo el *punto*, y con **parseFloat()** ya lo puedes convertir a número.