# Dar diferente formato a un número con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente numero:

```
var numero = 500000
```

y necesito que quede con este formato (₡5,000.00), de momento lo estoy así:

```
'₡'+`${total.toLocaleString("es-ES")}`;
```

pero no me funciona ya que la salida es esta (₡500.000)

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que agregarle **`minimumFractionDigits: 2`**, con esto separa decimales así sea números enteros. También el idioma del formato debería estar en **`en`** para que el separador de decimal sea con **`.`** y las milésimas con **`,`**:

```js
var numero = 500000

console.log('₡' + `${numero.toLocaleString("en",{minimumFractionDigits: 2})}`)
```

Comment: Me temo que esto no produce la salida que quiere el autor de la pregunta: `₡5,000.00`. Aprovecho para añadir que para obtener dicha salida lo correcto sería tener el número correcto... no es lógico querer representar el 5000.00 con un entero 500000. Lo correcto sería definir el numero como 5000.00 directamente, o solo 5000 y aplicarle el `minimumFractionDigits` tal como se hace en esta respuesta. Como workaround, si siempre el número va a tener la parte decimal representada por los dos últimos dígitos, se puede añadir un `numero /= 100` a la hora de representarlo.

Comment: el número es `500000` y lo que el autor desea es convertirlo a un formato de moneda (con el separador de decimales y milésimas), es lo que yo entendí.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, si necesito que la salida sea así (₡5,000.00).

Comment: con el número `500000`? porque si intentas con `5000` saldría el resultado =/.

Comment: por que es una suma de precios y por ejemplo hay precios "39.20" que al sumarlo con el 500000, quedaria mal al momento de mostrar el total.

Comment: @BrandonAlexisRubio Es que el problema principal es que usas 500000, no hay ningún problema en trabajar con números decimales... sumar 5000 + 39.20 daría 5039.20 sin ningún tipo de problema. Repito, no tiene sentido utilizar un número entero para representar un número que va a tener decimales porque si por algún motivo en algún momento tiene decimales, al dividirlo entre 100 te lo cargarás dando como resultado 50.3920

Comment: Estamos ante el típico [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY) creo yo.  No se como ha conseguido ese número, en una [anterior respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/568575/263200) a una pregunta suya le indiqué como hacer lo contrario, pero parece que ha agregado los decimales al número no se como y ahora quiere reconvertirlo de nuevo a moneda.